# React, Redux, Redux Saga - How do I constantly get notified with data from an external API?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, publish-subscribe, redux-saga

I am coding a web application with a frontend made up of React, Redux & Redux-Saga.

My backend is running on Express.

I am making a feature where users can join a "lobby" and get notified when other users have also joined the same lobby.

My question is how do you "listen" or "subscribe" to a source of outside data when using React and Redux? How can I listen for notifications on my client from my server?

Comment: use web socket, you need to implement it in the back end as well.

Comment: What are you asking specifically? Do you need to know something about the polling technique vs the web socket technique? Or are you asking about how you can manage it/them with Redux-saga?

Comment: if you're using Sagas, as per your tags, you're going to need to look at the `eventChannel`, can you clarify your question please?